# Safe remove USB/ SD Card that is mounted as a folder

Tags: c#

Im asking this question as im not too sure if it can be done and if it can how to go about doing it.

I have a program that uses data that is stored on a usb/sd card but before it can carry out its tasks the storage (either sd card or usb) is mounted to a folder as opposed to coming into windows as a drive letter. For example say the mounted folder is C:\documents\sdcard.

My question is this. Is there a way i can safe remove this storage in c# without unmounting the storage? Any pointers is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know - no. you have to unmount.

Comment: "remove this storage in c# without unmounting the storage" is pretty much the definition of an " _unsafe_ removal". This has nothing to do with C#, btw. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically write a method in c# that will safe eject the storage when the program has finished with the data on the storage device

Comment: @theNewOne92 "**without unmounting** the storage"

Comment: Yeah thats grand thanks. Wanted to make sure there was no way around it.